# Values inside items in string-array xml

Tags: android, xml, android-listview

Is something like this possible??

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <string-array name="planets_array">
    <item value=My >Mercury</item>
    <item value=Vs >Venus</item>
    <item value=EA >Earth</item>
    <item value=Ms >Mars</item>
  </string-array>
</resources>
```

the `listView` will show the planets but when the user selects Mars
the value I get will be `Ms`.

Comment: How about: `value + 1` to get your 4 when selecting Mars. It's really a standard way of working with arrays; 1st item is index 0.

Comment: If it's not 4 and it's a word? Let's say Ms for Mars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no such direct way to use string array in android app resources. One of my suggestion is separate the label and value to two different string arrays, then use these string arrays in your code.

```
<string-array name="planet_label">
    <item>Mercury</item>
    <item>Venus</item>
    <item>Earth</item>
    <item>Mars</item>
</string-array>
<string-array name="planet_values">
    <item>My</item>
    <item>Vs</item>
    <item>Ea</item>
    <item>Ms</item>
</string-array>
```

Comment: I can get a `planet_label` index and compare it to `planet_values`. Care to share some example of that?

Comment: @g90 The values in `planet_label` and `planet_values` are pair. `Mercury-My`, `Venus-Vs`, etc, so just use the index to locate the value from label.